# Add link to /editing-help in FAQ

Tags: feature-request, edits, faq-update-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could you please put a link to the Markdown help in the SO faq?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146375/could-you-please-put-a-link-to-the-markdown-help-in-the-so-faq)

The [${SITE}/editing-help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page is nice and useful, but hard to find. Not all users notice the question mark links in the top right corner of the editor. And not all ask questions, so they don't see the sidebar either.

For example, in [a feature request regarding blockquotes on †.SE meta](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/509/60), there was the following comment:

> I think the block quotes are nice...but someone has to keep doing them for me. I've looked for the instructions for doing these, but can't find any reference for special text editing. And, will the commands work on a MAC?

<sup>(This is from a new but quite active user. We have some active editors so probably many of the user's post had been edited to use blockquotes where appropriate.)</sup>

**Can we have a link to the editing help in the FAQ?** Many people probably expect to find one there.