# What is the Stack Overflow markup language syntax?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Has anyone a link to the Stack Exchange markup syntax?

Yeah, I know, surely there is another question like mine, but I can’t find it and need reference or something else, to let my questions be more interesting...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Markdown** is the answer *and* it's not only a markup language for the Stack Exchange network.
On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) you can read about the syntax or at the [official Stack Exchange support page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: ok, thanx for the link, but i'll post the Syntax in your answer in case the page gets deleted...

Comment: @Paedow: All of the syntax stuff you need is [already available directly on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Paedow, the [edit] links you had didn't work right, and you what was really amusing is that you used raw html instead of markdown for the answer (probably because it was cut-and-pasted).  You'll need to edit it better.

Comment: @animuson, yeh, I wish they would put a direct link on the sites for that, too me a little while to find when I was first looking for it.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Have you voted for this: [Could you please put a link to the Markdown help in the SO faq?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146375/could-you-please-put-a-link-to-the-markdown-help-in-the-so-faq)

Comment: @animuson, I hadn't seen that, but I've upvoted it now, and will bounty it if I remember when I have open slots.  Thanks.

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn´t know it -.-

Comment: Someone with sufficient privileges, please remove links to the official Stack Overflow/Exchange page(s) on Markdown. This confusing contribution does not mention </ol> for a list, nor does it mention that each line of a list should have <li> and </li>. The Wikipedia page is much more helpful. Computer help should include reasonably complete examples.

Comment: @DavidEpstein Markdown does not have `</ol>`, `<li>`, `</li>`, or any other angle-bracket tags for that matter. You may be thinking of HTML?

Comment: I have just looked athttp://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists

Comment: I have just looked at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists, and found <ol> WAS mentioned. Why??? It seems as though this page is even more bewildering and confusing than I had originally imagined. I was unable to create a numbered list based on the instructions given there. But I could construct a numbered list using <ol>, </ol>, <li> and </li>. Does this mean that Stack Exchange accepts HTML? I am thoughly bamboozled. The page ought to give an explicit example of a numbered list, instead of referring to <ol>.

Comment: @DavidEpstein : I know your question was old, but I saw no answer given to you.  [Meta: What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) does, indeed, show <ol> (not allowed in comments like this, but allowed in questions and answers)