# Why Isn't Editing Help on the FAQ's Section?

Tags: support, edits, markdown, help

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add link to /editing-help in FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107571/add-link-to-editing-help-in-faq)

I've seen a couple of requests regarding [Add link to /editing-help in FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107571/add-link-to-editing-help-in-faq) but it apparently only picked up four votes.

> **Is there a good reason why the [FAQ's Page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) doesn't include either a link to or an answer for [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and markdown basics?**

Comment: Yeah ... that's why I included it in the first line ... please read.

Comment: Start a bounty. Do not repost the question. A duplicate is a duplicate is a duplicate.

Comment: My question is regarding 'WHY' it's not included ... so it's a valid  question ...

Comment: One good reason is that [the reference to suicide in the Markdown help page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142099/what-formatting-example-should-replace-his-suicide-note-in-the-markdown-help)  hasn't yet been removed.

Comment: @Yannis ... Ahh ... maybe ...

Comment: @Yannis It's not a _great_ reason: why not make the edit, _then_ add the link?

Comment: @AndrewC You'll have to ask someone else why the edit hasn't been made yet, I've been waiting for it since August (it's my question, after all...)

Comment: @Yannis Who does the editing?

Comment: @AndrewC The help pages are only editable by SE, as is most of the FAQ (its first part only - What kind of questions can I ask here? - is also editable by diamond mods).

Comment: @Yannis Is there any chance we can attract SE's attention to this? It gets asked every so often by newish users (including [me a few months ago when I was new](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146375/could-you-please-put-a-link-to-the-markdown-help-in-the-so-faq)), but ironically none of the established users see it as important enough to do anything about.

Comment: @AndrewC I started a bounty on the duplicate, that usually gets SE's attention.

Comment: @Yannis Hopefully that will bring fruition ... The current SO bureaucracy regarding duplicates shouldn't impede altruism for quality.